# SSRS - Impersonate user

Tags: reporting-services, datasource

I have a SSRS report for which the Datasource is connected via Database credentials. Now I wanted to restrict a parameter dropdown based on the user using the report.

I tried impersonating the user but it didnt work.
I tried getting the User!UserID within SSRS, but it didn't work.

How can I get the Windows login of the user? Is there any other way or am I missing anything?

Edit -
Not everyone in the organisation has got access to the Database, hence we use the Database user login. But we have a table which holds the AD login and using that I need to restrict the drop down lists in the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the credentials on the datasource to use windows authentication. If this is a shared datasource you might have to create a new datasource that use windows authentication and point your datasets to that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Alan Schofield
Not everyone in the organisation has got access to the Database, hence we use the Database user login. But we have a table which holds the AD login and using that I need to restrict the drop down lists in the parameter.

Comment: OK, Can you explain what you mean by restricting a parameter drop down. Do you mean  only some options will be available based on the user? If so can you show an exmaple of what your user tale looks like, what the parameter list looks like and a couple of scenarios with different users.